# How to substitute values here recievied while parsing a xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following xml file

```
<categories>

  <category id="2" name="Pepsi" >
     <products>
      <product id="858" name="7UP" price="24.4900" />
      <product id="860" name="Aquafina" price="24.4900" />
      </products>
  </category>

  <category id="4" name="Coke" >
     <products>
      <product id="811" name="ThumpsUp" price="24.4900" />
      <product id="813" name="Maaza" price="24.4900" />
    </products>
  </category>

 </categories>
```

Which i am parsing it using Jquery

```
$(xmldocu).find("category").each(function () {
    var names = $(this).attr('name');//.text();
     alert(names);
    });
```

Please look at the JSFiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/GTf6c/

How can i create the activateUi.newPanel.html with the category elements i recievied while parsing xml

```
activateUi.newPanel.html(" \
                    <h3><a href='#'>First</a></h3> \
                    <div></div> \
                    <h3><a href='#'>Second</a></h3> \
                    <div></div> \
                    <h3><a href='#'>Third</a></h3><div></div>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var names = []; //make an empty array to store the category names
$(xmldocu).find("category").each(function () {
    names.push($(this).attr('name')); //add each category name to the array
});

var activateUiHTML = $("<div></div>"); //make an empty div to store the new HTML
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    // loop through each name, and create the desired markup for each category name
    activateUiHTML.append("<h3><a href='#'>" + names[i] + "</a></h3><div></div>");
}

activateUi.newPanel.html(activateUiHTML); //set the new markup as the html
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but its breaking the existing functionality

Comment: If you see my  http://jsfiddle.net/GTf6c/ , if i put your code inside that , the Accordians are not displaying .

Comment: The answer I wrote was based on the information you provided in your question.

Comment: looks good , but the nested Accordians are unable to create Accordians as required .

Comment: You have been pretty unclear as to exactly what you're trying to do here. I feel that my original answer was sufficient to the question you asked. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks pmandell , the last jsfiddle is what i required , thank you very much . and sorry if i confused you .